# how to remove light grey color around checkbutton widgets tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently had a problem when I was trying to set an image on the background of my app, I want to send it in background and have all entries and stuff over. All the text will be incuded in the picture itself so I got no problem on that point.
The fact is that I can't just set the CheckButton on the picture because it is needed (we have to check it / uncheck) so I would like to make it with no shadow / outline (Check picture) caused by the height and width.
I want to know if there is a way to disable width and height or even set it to 0 but it is impossible.

I tried to set height / width to 0 and some other attributes but nothing helped me

`Checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(scanallnet, variable=check_var, command=toogle_active, bg="lightgray", activebackground="lightgray", width=0, height=0)`

The best thing would be an invisible background but that's hard to do (or if you have any other idea). But I prefer to set the outline invisible or inexistant.

Comment: This is not pure python; please tag with whatever library you're using in addition to Python.

Comment: I can't set the tag tkinter but it is this library

Comment: Why can't you set it? Some SO restriction I don't know about?

Comment: are you aware of the `borderwidth` attribute?

Comment: It looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/jN9feun But the ouline can't be set to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries and fails I decided to recreate a Checkbutton with the property `indicatoron=0` to make a simple button that remains pushed when clicked. Then i added a bitmap with a check mark "✓" inside and here's the result.

[image: R]

Thanks for your advices anyway but this result fit perfectly with what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> The two components which affect the edges: the border (borderwidth
>   attribute) and highlight ring (highlightthickness attribute).

If you have a border width of zero and a highlight thickness of zero, the widgeta coordinates will begin at 0,0.

**This will work**

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()
Checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(win,highlightthickness=0,bd=0).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

[image]

Remove this all stuff from your code :**bg="lightgray", activebackground="lightgray", width=0, height=0**

Comment: No it doesn't for me, I have a custom background and I always have this outline: https://imgur.com/a/qyPAdHf
```Checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(scanallnet, variable=check_var, command=toogle_active, highlightthickness=0,bd=0)```

Comment: Try with a random picture: 
```BG = Image.open(__picpath__)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BG)
BGL = Label(scanallnet, image=img)
BGL.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)```

Comment: To resume, I have tested your code and many arguments on my CheckButton but I don't have something changing...
```from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = Tk()
BG = Image.open("ScanAllNet.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BG)
BGL = Label(win, image=img)
BGL.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)


Checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(win, highlightthickness=0, bd=0).pack()
win.mainloop()```
And It result to same as before : https://imgur.com/a/DiZkXKZ
BTW I'm on windows but it should do the same on MAC / LINUX.
EDIT Idk how to indent code