# Is there a way to remove the checkbutton border in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to remove the border around a checkbutton? I have tried `relief = "flat"`, `offrelief = "flat"`, `borderwidth = 0` and `highlightthickness = 0` and none of these have made any difference. I also found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617962/how-to-remove-light-grey-color-around-checkbutton-widgets-tkinter), but the first answer doesn't work, and the second involves recreating the widget, but I wish to use the Checkbutton widget. The reason I need to remove the border is that I'm wrapping the button in a frame to change it's border, and If I can't remove the default border, it isn't possible.

This is the border I mean:
[image: Checkbutton]

Comment: ***This is the border I mean:***: You image shows the Checkbutton image instead of a **border**. Do you want to replace the Checkbutton image instead? Read up on [Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method - 'image='](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method)

Comment: @stovfl No, I still want the check mark and using image does nothing to change the actual chekbox. I mean the raised relief around the checkmark, like in this image: https://i.imgur.com/33l3cCS.png

Comment: Your linked question, answer using `highlightthickness=0,bd=0` works for me. Therefore your environment, OS, Version, Theme, doesent support what you want.